# Choosing the right regression model

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I'm trying to see whether the number of salesman per customer entering the store affect the sales amount using a simple OLS regression. Which one is a better model to test the hypothesis? Can you also tell me why?

Model 1:sales= B1+ B2(salesman/customers entering the store).

Model 2:sales=B1 + B2 *salesman + B3 * entering tore+B4* (salesman/store size)

Comment: This type of question is too vague for any reader to be able to provide useful feedback. I recommend adding more details and narrowing your question. If your concern is model assessment, there are many previous threads discussing methods for OLS regression.

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: You need data to determine which model is better.

Answer (score 0):

Split your sample in two: training and validation. Estimate both models on the training and pick the model that performs the best (in mean squares error) on the validation dataset.